# How to expand nested Abs

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to expand this:

```
FullSimplify[Abs[1 - Abs[x]], x \[Element] Reals]
```

how can I do this? Evidently this function can be presented as

```
A Abs[x] + B Abs[x-1] + C Abs[x+1] + D x + E
```

so how can I force FullSimplify to expand it?

Comment: Check out `out = PiecewiseExpand[Abs[1 - Abs[x]], x \[Element] Reals]` and also ``Simplify`PWToUnitStep@out//FullSimplify``.

Comment: `Abs[1 - Abs[x]] == - Abs[x] + Abs[x - 1] + Abs[x + 1] - 1`

Comment: @corey979, this doesn't give me result as sum of Abs...

Comment: Note that simplifying in *Mathematica* usually means finding a compact, as opposed to an expanded, expression.

Answer (score 4):

In fact all the continuous piecewise function can be represent by non-nested absolute value functions.

> Consider the function on the interval from a to b: $f(x)\in[a,b]$
>
> The value of the function other than from a to b is $0$.
>
> It can be written as:
>
> $$f\left(\frac{1}{2} \left(a+b+\left|x-a\right|-\left|x-b\right|\right)\right)-f(b)$$

---

Well, now we can expand all kinds of nested absolute value functions.

[image: Simple situation]

```
AbsExpand[expr_] := Module[
    {EqCheck, out, dk, pBase, Dom2Base, DomainCheck},
    EqCheck = {LessEqual -> Less, GreaterEqual -> Greater};
    pBase[a_, b_, fx_] := (fx /. {x -> (a + b + Sqrt[(x - a)^2] - Sqrt[(x - b)^2]) / 2}) - (fx /. {x -> b});
    pBase[a_, ComplexInfinity, fx_] := fx /. {x -> (x + a + Sqrt[(x - a)^2]) / 2};
    pBase[ComplexInfinity, b_, fx_] := (fx /. {x -> (x + b - Sqrt[(x - b)^2]) / 2}) - (fx /. {x -> b});
    DomainCheck[{dom_, fx_}] := Module[
        {edom = dom /. EqCheck},
        If[Head[edom] === Equal, Return[Nothing]];
        If[Head[edom] === Or,
            Sequence @@ Map[{#, fx}&, List @@ edom],
            {edom, fx}
        ]
    ];
    Dom2Base[{dom_, fx_}] := Module[
        {},
        If[Head@dom === Greater, Return@pBase[Last@dom, ComplexInfinity, fx]];
        If[Head@dom === Less, Return@pBase[ComplexInfinity, Last@dom, fx]];
        pBase[First@dom, Last@dom, fx]
    ];
    out = PiecewiseExpand[expr, x\[Element]Reals] // FullSimplify // PiecewiseExpand;
    dk = DomainCheck /@ Transpose[Internal`FromPiecewise@out];
    Total[Dom2Base /@ dk] /. {Sqrt[(f__)^2] :> Abs[f]}
];
```

I think it should be able to deal with all complex situations.

[image: Complex situation]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a model, such as a linear combination of `{1, x, Abs[x], Abs[x - 1], Abs[x + 1]}`, you can use [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html):

```
LinearModelFit[
  Table[{x, Abs[1 - Abs[x]]}, {x, -10, 10}], (* need enough for full rank design matrix *) 
  {x, Abs[x], Abs[x - 1], Abs[x + 1]},
  {x}, WorkingPrecision -> Infinity][x]

(*  -1 + Abs[-1 + x] - Abs[x] + Abs[1 + x]  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consequently Working with `PiecewiseExpand` can give the solution.

```
expr = Abs[1 - Abs[x]];

guess = A Abs[x] + B Abs[x - 1] + C Abs[x + 1] + D x + EE;

sol = Solve[ForAll[x, x \[Element] Reals, 
        PiecewiseExpand[guess, x \[Element] Reals] == 
        PiecewiseExpand[expr, x \[Element] Reals]], {A, B, C, D, EE}]

(*   {{A -> -1, B -> 1, C -> 1, D -> 0, EE -> -1}}   *)

guess /. First@sol

(*   -1 + Abs[-1 + x] - Abs[x] + Abs[1 + x]   *)
```

Test

```
PiecewiseExpand[guess /. First@sol, x \[Element] Reals] == 
PiecewiseExpand[expr, x \[Element] Reals] // Simplify

(*   True   *)
```